# Text field on UIAlertController goes below the action buttons

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

So, I'm stumped...Here's the image for quick reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K399u.png

The issue is that when a textField is added to a UIAlertController, the textfield's height is larger than one line, and goes underneath the UIAlertController buttons. Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Here's the code:

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                         message:@"Message"
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                     handler:nil];

UIAlertAction *resetDataAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                                // handler code
                                                        }];

[alertController addAction:resetDataAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        //handler code
}];


[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: are you adding any subviews to the controller or did you convert it from the iOS7 UIAlertView?

Comment: No added subviews, just using the iOS8 stock `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler` for UIAlertController. To note: it happens even when I use UIAlertView and`alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`.

Answer (score 0):

because you add buttons then your text field.

```
[alertController addAction:resetDataAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    //handler code
}];
```

but you need to do it like that

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    //handler code
}];
[alertController addAction:resetDataAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
```